# How to update dependencies locally on an Amplify Python Lambda function?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I'm new to Amplify and trying to create a Python Lambda, but having difficulties with dependencies when running locally.  I've created the function through Amplify CLI and when I run it with either `amplify function invoke myFunc` or the newer recommendation `amplify mock function myFunc` I get no errors and the boilerplate response displays just fine.

I've tried to do a `pipenv install requests` both within and outside of the virtual shell and I see that the `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` have been updated, and I get the "installing dependencies" progress, but if I add an `import requests` to the `index.py` I end up with a:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

I have also tried to force a build with `amplify function build` and still no luck.

If I do an `amplify push`, however, and run it live on AWS, it works just fine.  What am I missing on the local side?

Comment: Could you share the folder structure?

I've a similar issue with project like so:

**rooProject/amplify/backend/function/functionName**

The Pipfile
```bash
[packages]
src = {editable = true, path = "./src"}
# more packages
mypackage = {editable = false, path = "../../mypackage/dist/rentline-0.3.0.tar.gz"}
```

The index.py imports another package living under:

**rooProject/amplify/backend/mypackage/**

When I run `amplify mock function functionName -y --debug`

In my case the error is the same but wondering about your project structure.

Answer (score 2):

In your CLI go though the folder until you reach the function you are working on... and then execute the pipenv install

Ex:
...\amplify\backend\function\YOUR_FUNCION> pipenv install requests

Comment: I've the same structure, and this works locally. When you want to deploy your changes. The amplify process can't find the packages that are inside of the backend folder. For some reason during the deployment the mapping is not there.